# html - select option not selected by user - validation

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

This is the script i am using for select a city. But the user proceeded without any selection from the list.

```
<select>
<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
<option>City 1</option>
<option>City 2</option>
<option>City 3</option>
</select>
```

After user Submits the form, errors comes like "Notice: Undefined index: CITY in /home/...../public_html/address.php on line 44
Column 'CITY' cannot be null"

How to validate it before Submit the form?

Comment: What does your `address.php` look like?

Comment: your select should have `name="city"`

Comment: You can add `selected` property to one of your options to select it by default. In any case, you will need some form of validation on the server side since form values are ultimately controlled by the client.

Comment: Use javascript to validate before submit the form.
And in `address.php` check the value with `isset`

Answer (score 1):

**php**

```
<?php
$message='';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    if (!isset($_POST['city']) || $_POST['city'] === '') {
    $message .= " Please Select The City First <br />";
    }
}

if(isset($message))
{
echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:12px;">'.$message.'</div>';
}

?>
```

**HTML**

```
   <select name="city" selected disabled >
     <option value="city1">City 1</option>
     <option value="city2">City 2</option>
     <option value="city3">City 3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="city">
  <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="London">London</option>
</select>
```

You need to give the option a value

Answer (score 0):

Place `select` to the form, add `required`, `name` and `value` attribute:

```
<form>
    <select name="city" required>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value="city1">City 1</option>
        <option value="city2">City 2</option>
        <option value="city3">City 3</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Vesmy, just added "required" after "select" it it works now. Even though there are some other options using java script, I thought it is simple and just using HTML

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like this. This way the your select will have a value when sent. And adding the "required" will make sure that the user will have to select before submitting.

```html
<select name="city" required>
  <option selected disabled>SELECT CITY</option>
  <option value="City 1">City 1</option>
  <option value="city 2">City 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a javascript validation or your code. therefore it cannot be null. this code will block the submit, before you select.
Here is the html form,

```
 <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return(Validate());" name="myform">
        <select name="city">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value="City 1">City 1</option>
        <option value="City 1">City 2</option>
        </select>
        <div id="name_error" style="color:red;"></div>
    </form>
```

Here is the JS part

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
      // Form validation code will come here.

      function Validate()
      {

         if( document.myform.city.value == "" )
         {
            alert( "Please provide your city!" );

            name_error.textContent = "City is Required.!"; 
            document.myform.city.focus() ;
            return false;
         }


         return( true );
      }
   //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the select tag required and pass value for each option. That will do the rest on your client side validation

```
<form method = 'post' action='address.php'>
<select required>
<option value =""> -- select an option -- </option>
<option value ="city1">City 1</option>
<option value ="city1">City 2</option>
<option value ="city1">City 3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

and if you also wants server side validation you must include a name attribute in the select tag.

```
<form method ='post' action='address.php'>
    <select name="cities" required>
    <option value =""> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value ="city1">City 1</option>
    <option value ="city1">City 2</option>
    <option value ="city1">City 3</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

and form the name you can get the value of the select option and do further what you want

```
$city = $_POST['cities'];
```